I am getting errors in console when trying to interact with Kentio RTE
I am developing website in .NET 6 MVC with Kentico 13 and i created a widget with only two properties: content, background color. The first one has editing component as RTE. But when I want to set this widget on page and I'm getting into RTE nothing is clickable. I can't type and buttons are doing nothing. I checked brower's console and I saw some errors. When I'm trying to perform an action new error occures in console.
VER: Kentico 13 Xperience, hotfix 121
I have my widget like this
public class EditableTextProperties : IWidgetProperties
{
    [EditingComponent(RichTextComponent.IDENTIFIER, Label = "Text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [EditingComponent(DropDownComponent.IDENTIFIER, Order = 30, Label = "Section background color")]
    [EditingComponentProperty(nameof(DropDownProperties.DataSource),
        @";None (White)
            section--bg-gray;Grey
            section--bg-beige;Beige
            bg-secondary color-white;Dark Purple
            section--bg-white-rock;White Rock")]
    public string BackgroundColor { get; set; }
}

When I'm clicking "Edit" Widget props in Kentico when trying to edit widget I see RTE  RTE. Nothing is clickable, can't type and I am getting errors in console on button clicks Error
I know this is not much, but it's all that I am doing with this widget. And it happens withe every widget using RTE
